# Why does let lose its value in React?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have this React code. `organizationId` is a `let` variable, it is written as you see. First and sendond I can see the value, but 3rd not, how is it possible? It is Next.js based project.

```
function Event(props: EventProps) {
  const { lang, translations, eventId } = props;
  const [event, setEvent] = useState<EventOut | undefined>();
  const [enableSaleSwitch, setEnableSaleSwitch] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [
    enableSaleSwitchOnWordpress,
    setEnableSaleSwitchOnWordpress,
  ] = useState<boolean>(false);
  let isTiketAdmin: string | null;
  let jwt: string | null;
  let eventIdNew: string | undefined;
  let organizationId: string | undefined;
  let organization: OrganizationOut | undefined;
  let userFbId: string | null;
  let permission: string | undefined;

  useEffect(() => {
    isTiketAdmin = localStorage.getItem("isTiketAdmin");
    jwt = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
    userFbId = localStorage.getItem("userFbId");
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    organizationId = getOrganizationFbIdFromEventId(eventId);
    if (organizationId != undefined) {
      organization = getOrganizationByFbId(organizationId!);
      if (organization && userFbId) {
        permission = organization.usersWithPermission[userFbId];
        setEvent(organization.events[eventId]);
      }
    }
  }, [eventId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (event) {
      if (checkEnableSaleOnTiket(event, eventId)) {
        setEnableSaleSwitch(true);
      } else {
        setEnableSaleSwitch(false);
      }
      if (checkEnableSaleOnWordPress(event, eventId)) {
        setEnableSaleSwitchOnWordpress(true);
      } else {
        setEnableSaleSwitchOnWordpress(false);
      }
    }
  }, [event]);
```

[image]

Comment: Is `getOrganizationFbIdFromEventId(...)` an `async` function?

Comment: The way to define and update mutable values in React is done through `useRef`

Comment: No, it is not async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should describe what happens and why it's not what you expect, instead of just posting a GIF image.

As an actual answer, why does it matter? Your dependency array for that `useEffect` doesn't specify `organizationId`.

What happens is:

1. **First render**, all `useEffects` hooks are set to run.
2. 2nd hook runs first *(ignoring the unrelated 1st hook)*. It assigns `organizationId`.
3. 2nd hook calls `setEvent`, queueing a re-render **for later**.
4. 3rd hook runs afterwards (in "parallel") and sees the updated value.
5. **Second render**, caused by step 3.
6. 2nd hook **does not run** because `eventId` didn't change. Its dependency array says to only rerun the hook effect if `eventId` changes. Therefore `organizationId` is **not** set again.
7. 3rd hook is run because `event` changed. As seen in step 6, the previous hook didn't run this render, therefore the variable is not set.

If you have a variable you need to keep between renders and share with hooks, make it a state variable or a ref. E.g. use `useState` or `useRef`, depending on whether updating the variable should re-render the component.

Comment: Why value is not seen, if it was assigned before? Before I did use too many useState variable, and someone told try to keep less `useState` and have more `let`. I took it seriously.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68571812/react-shall-uniqe-usestate-variables-created-for-each-field

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding how functional components work. When your component gets (re-)rendered, it gets (re-)called. Meaning that every render, all variables in your function scope (e.g. `organizationId`) are fresh variables, and not the same as the previous render. That's why you need to use `useState` or `useRef`, so React can make sure that your state/refs stay the same between renders.